# Cursor description (columns list) is a 7-tuple even though only one column in the resultset

Tags: python, sqlite

I am using the `sqlite` connector and examining the `cursor` returned from a `query`:

```
  curs = s.conn.cursor()
  curs.execute("select count(distinct category) as ncats from part")
  rows = curs.fetchall()
```

Examining the `curs.description()` in the debugger we see it is a 7-tuple of the single column `ncats` plus 6 `None`s.

```
print(f'cursor description type: {type(curs.description)} 
        len: {len(curs.description[0])}')

cursor description type: <class 'tuple'> len: 7
```

Well the more the merrier ??  What are these for - and should we expect there to always be six extra participants in the results?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#cursor-objects):

> **description**
>
> This read-only attribute provides the column names of the last query. To remain compatible with the Python DB API, it returns a 7-tuple for each column where the last six items of each tuple are None.

From the [DB API documentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#cursor-attributes):

> Each of these sequences contains information describing one result column:
>
> - name
> - type_code
> - display_size
> - internal_size
> - precision
> - scale
> - null_ok
>
> The first two items (name and type_code) are mandatory, the other five are optional and are set to None if no meaningful values can be provided.

`name` is the only one of those that makes sense given sqlite's type system.